# How do permissions work in the Android Market?

Tags: security, permissions

I've been told that the permissions for an app are there to inform me the types of things the app has permission to do. If this is right, can a developer 'forget' a permission and get away with using something anyway.  I'm just curious for the security of my device.  I know that Google does not police it's market as strict as Apple so I was wondering if a app could 'forget' to claim a permission but use that feature anyway?

This is not a programming question - its about the trustworthiness of permissions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The permissions are entered by the developer, yes.  But the Android OS only grants those specific permissions, and no others.  Therefore an app could **try** to do something it wasn't allowed to, but it would fail (barring a security exploit).  See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html#permissions for more details.

Answer (score 5):

If a developer "forget" to require a permission, they will be unable to use the feature, and they will (usually) get a force close (you will be able to observe this in logcat) or fails to do its work.

Comment: Which also, unfortunately, leads to some lazy developers to set their app to need more permissions than it actually needs.

Answer (score 4):

The permissions are what allows an app to do something. If an app doesn't ask for a permission, then it can't do that thing.

See [Security and Permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html) on the Android Developer site for more info.

*Note that if you have a rooted phone, and allow the app superuser access then it can do pretty much whatever it wants. Make sure you trust any app that you give this access to!*